# Why doesn't my .js file appear to do anything to my .html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a basic image slider that just automatically slides through any given amount of images placed inside a div.

HTML

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="images">
        <img class="slides" src="img01.jpg">
        <img class="slides" src="img02.jpg">            
        <img class="slides" src="img03.jpg">        
        <img class="slides" src="img04.jpg">    
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

But at the moment, it seems that this code isn't doing anything at all, this is the current output of the page.
[image]

So as you can see, the images are just being stacked on top of one and another instead of being played as a slideshow.

Comment: And for anyone who is going to ask, my .html file and .js file are in the same folder, I know it's not a path issue

Comment: First of all, you call carousel before defining the function...

Comment: @Shautieh that's allowed in JS. Read about JS hoisting.

Comment: Follow what has been done here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto. Its very helpful in your case.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I didn't know about this one! Never saw anyone use this, and it's very ugly IMHO, but it indeed works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading your script before the HTML is rendered, so when it tries to `getElementsByClassName`, there's nothing for it to find.  Try moving to to below your HTML.  And as a in a comment above, you're calling your function `carousel()` before you define it.  Move that line to below the function definition.

Additionally, you can use

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        // all of your JavaScript goes here
    });
</script>
```

This will only load your JavaScript after the HTML is loaded and you can leave it in the head.

Comment: @LiamEmery I also added some info about waiting until the DOM has loaded to call your JavaScript, which is probably a preferable way to do this.  When sites start to get larger and more complex, the last thing you want to worry about is placement of things when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Put the carousel(); call after the html. That way the javascript won't be invoked before the html is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to the carousel method after the images have been loaded. You can do  the following in your javascript file "slider.js"

```
window.onload = function() { casousel(); };
```

This would invoke the carousel function on window load.